# Import old email from Opera to Gmail

Tags: gmail, import

Does anyone know how can I move all the email I have in Opera 12 to a Gmail account linked to Google Apps?

Comment: What is your current email service? If I'm not mistaken Opera doesn't host an email service? When someone emails you, what do they write after the @-sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn how to import email to Gmail [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/164640?hl=en). Unfortunately, it appears that you can't import email from Opera.